# javascript box not to show - values

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want that my negative character should not display when the user click - button. The counting should end on 0. 
It is now showing -1, -2,-3 characters also. I want to show only 0 or more than 0

```
<script type="text/javascript" >                                
            function plus(){
                var addplus = 1;
                var plus = document.getElementById('qty').value;
                addplus = parseInt(addplus) + parseInt(plus); 
                document.getElementById('qty').value = addplus;
            }
            function negtive(){
                var neg;
                var negtive = 1;
                var negtives = document.getElementById('qty').value;
                negtive = parseInt(negtives) - parseInt(negtive);               
                document.getElementById('qty').value = negtive;             
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: Spelling of negative is "negative", not "negtive"

Answer (score 2):

Put this line

```
if(negtive<0)
    negtive = 0;
```

after

```
negtive = parseInt(negtives) - parseInt(negtive);
```

OR

```
document.getElementById('qty').value = ((negtive <0)?0:negtive );
```

Comment: i just want that  my negative values should now show in the box

Comment: Please check once again.. You misspelled negative.. Correct it in answer.. copy and paste it..